# Why i have a link that sends me to a jsp perfectly the first time but whenever i get to click that link again it display an error

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am working in mvc web application with servlets and jsp with database connection

i have a link in a jsp that send me to a another jsp where I can register
another employee

`<a href="registrarempleado.jsp" > Add new employee</a>`

in the jsp where it send us we can register a new employee and stored the information in a database , once we click the button register the servlet
bring us back to  the first jsp where the link add new employee is but if i click it again to add another employee it gives me this error

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

Comment: Probably because you're using relative paths, from a JSP that is not at the same hierarchy level. Look at the URLs in your location bar. Note that you tagged your question with mvc, but that you link from a view to a view, thus bypassing controllers, thus not using mvc.

Comment: Ok I'm going to edit that

Comment: Sorry I'm just a beginner can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I was sending from the servlet to the jsp a parameter with a request dispatcher instead of using a response.sendredirect , an for that reason I wasn't really in the jsp I was still in the servlet and that's why the link didn't work again